# ¿Cómo mostrar una web en un iframe que contiene el carácter # en mitad de la URL en Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Tengo un problema, y es que tengo un `iframe` que en Chrome y en Firefox funciona correctamente, pero en Internet Explorer no (que sorpresa).

El `iframe` es el siguiente:

```
<iframe id="soyUnFrame" src="https://proyectos.es/niku/nu#action:c_rally_dashboard&amp;id=6326001&amp;puiFullscreen=on&amp;puiHidePPMTabs=on&amp;quitarCabeceras=1" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 1300px;"></iframe>
```

Y no carga nada, por lo que el contenido del iframe es:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Por lo que he podido investigar, Internet Explorer utiliza el carácter # para dar saltos a cierto contenido dentro de la página, por lo que en el `iframe` lo interpreta como que ahí está el corte de la URL y el resto de URL es donde debe de saltar. En mi caso, por la herramienta que estoy utilizando (CA PPM) siempre debe tener detrás del dominio el /niku/nu#action: , por lo que no se muy bien cual puede ser la solución.

Ya he probado a sustituir el # por su carácter en HTML y en ASCII, pero tampoco funciona.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

NOTA: La URL es de una intranet.

Saludos.

Dani.

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en la consola de IE? Asumo que estás usando la versión 11. **NOTA**: La parte de la URL que está después del `#` no se envía al servidor en IE, pero tampoco se envía en Chrome o Firefox, es información para el navegador

Comment: @PabloLozano En la consola de IE no se muestra ningún log, ni de información ni de error, y la llamada get que tendría que hacer para obtener la web que consulto, tampoco se llega a efectuar.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo Windows y por tanto no puedo comprobarlo, pero creo que el problema es que IE intenta evitar un bucle infinito sin tener en cuenta que estás en una SPA. Los navegadores modernos tienen un mejor diseño de está protección y son capaces de averiguar cuándo esto es un problema.

Paso a explicar el escenario:

1. El navegador carga una URL con la forma `http://dominio/applicacion#info_extra`.

   1. El navegador elimina todo lo que viene tras la almohadilla/gato (carácter `#`) porque es información para el navegador, no para el servidor, por lo que realmente pide el recurso `http://dominio/applicacion`.
   2. El servidor responde con el HTML, JS, CSS... lo que se necesite para cargar la web
2. La web cargada incluye un `iframe` con la URL `http://dominio/applicacion#otra_info_extra`.

   1. De nuevo el navegador elimina la parte que no le interesa al servidor.
   2. El navegador reconoce que la URL del iframe **es la misma** que la de la página padre. Asume que se va a cargar la misma página, que tendrá otro iframe, que a su vez tendrá otro iframe.... y así infinitas veces, hasta que el sistema se quede sin memoria y falle. Para protegerse de este problema, omite la carga y genera un HTML vacío.

- Solución: crear en el servidor un recurso que realmente sea un clon del primero: Si la URL `http://dominio/applicacion/ignora-esta-parte#otra_info_extra` apunta al mismo recurso que `http://dominio/applicacion/#otra_info_extra`, el navegador IE no aplicará esta protección.